# CodeIgniter : Undefined index in model variable

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, object, indexing, model

I have the below code in of of my models. Im loading the offer details page and it gave me the error

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: viewc

Filename: statistics/Statistic_model.php

Line Number: 551
```

**Statistic_model:**

```
public function getTotalDetailsViewOfActiveOffer($comid) {

    $this->db->select('count(statistic_offer_view_count.id) as viewc');
    $this->db->from('statistic_offer_view_count');
    $this->db->join('offers', 'offers.id = statistic_offer_view_count.offer_id');       
    $this->db->where('offers.com_id',$comid);
    $this->db->where('offers.approved_status',"2"); 
    $this->db->where('offers.enddate >=',date('Y-m-d'));
    $this->db->group_by("offers.com_id");       
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $row = $query->result_array();
    $count=$row['viewc'];           //this is line 551

}
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that the index `viewc` is not in the array `$query->result_array()` most likely because your query failed or returned null. You should get into the habit of doing:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->row()->viewc;
}
return false; // or in this case 0 or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your Code You Selecting data from database Multiple array's.And assigning at to a variable like a single array.
Your Code....

```
$row = $query->result_array();
$count=$row['viewc'];
```

correct way is in your conduction to assign a variable is....

```
$data   =   array();
foreah($row as $key => $value){
  $data[$key] = $value['viewc'];
}
```